# Mixing augmented and original samples using tf.data.Dataset.map()

Tags: python, tensorflow

As far as I understood from tensor flow documentation map is used to modify the image based on the function parse_function_wrapper.

```
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function_wrapper,
                  num_parallel_calls=4)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
```

Now the dataset will have only the augmented images does not have the original images. So my doubt here is we need to train our model with original data as well as augmented data. Can anyone tell me how to train with the original data also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two simple solutions:

1) Keep the original dataset and the augmented one, then zip them, flat_map and shuffle:

```
augmented = dataset.map(parse_function_wrapper,
                  num_parallel_calls=4)
mixed_dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.zip([dataset, augmented])
                 .flat_map(lambda x: x)
                 .shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)) # use an appropriate buffer size
```

2) Make `parse_function_wrapper` stochastic by applying augmentation with probability `p < 1` and returning the unmodified input with probability `1-p`. This, plus repeating your dataset, obtains a similar effect to the previous solution, but it's logically simpler to understand. Moreover, this way you can control much better the ratio of augmented vs original samples in your training dataset, since you can explicitly set what percentage of the "mixed" dataset should be augmented data.

Comment: Just about to suggest your second approach :D